# Was Zoroaster A Disciple Of Prophet Jeremiah?

Tags: sunnah

Was Zoroaster a disciple of prophet Jeremiah according to the Sunna?

Answer (score 1):

Neither Zoroaster and Jeremiah are mentioned in Quran or any sahih hadith; we can't say if they were Prophets.

Zoroaster is said to live around 1500BC, while Jeremiah lived during the time of John the Baptist.  There was a major time gap between the two. So, no.

Comment: Do you have any sources to back up the assertions you make in the last paragraph? Because some rather basic [fact](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jeremiah)-[checking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zoroaster#Date) on Wikipedia suggests that (a) there is no consensus as to the date of Zoroaster, with scholars proposing dates "between the 18th and the 6th centuries BCE", and (b) Jeremiah's ministry was around the 7th century BCE, which is about six centuries *before* John the Baptist ever showed up.